# 3 white wires and 1 black wire in ceiling fixture

Tags: wiring

I recently moved into a home that had one of the light fixtures missing in the bedroom, I'm going to assume that it was a ceiling fan due to the bracket that was left behind. I'm trying to put up light fixture that has 1 white,1black and a ground wire. The wires in the ceiling have 3 white wires bundled together with a wire nut black wire with wire nut and the ground wire. How do I know which white wire to use and when I separate the white wires do they need to be wire nut  separately or can two white wires go together

Comment: Can you post a photo of what's inside the box?

Answer (score 1):

The black wire is the hot wire, the white wires are neutral and ground is ground. You need to connect the black wire of your light fixture to the black ceiling wire, the white wire fixture to the 3 white wires, and the ground wire to the ground wire. You have to maintain the connection of the 3 existing white wires. You may need a larger wire nut to connect your fixture white wire to the existing 3 white wires. It may be better to use a jumper wire and 2 wire nuts to connect the 4 white wires together.